# Using the Authorise Route for trello OAuth, then get token after hash tag#

Tags: node.js, oauth, trello

According to the reference link `https://developers.trello.com/authorize`, I choose the first way **Using the Authorize Route** to implement OAuth on Trello.
The involved url request is `https://trello.com/1/authorize?return_url=http://xxx/union/callback/trello&namae=xxx&key=xxx&callback_method=xxx&scope=read&expiration=30days`

Finally, the program stops with url `http://xxx/union/callback/trello#token=a1418eb97b298edc9a7a83fb85107bad4d2861cf46ac897037002aff778c3927` on the browser location.

In my opinion, token should be returned after "?" instead of "#".
Because string after "#" will not be sent to server.

For this issue, is it a bug of trello's OAuth or I can do anything to proceed ?

Comment: No idea what your stack and goal is, but you can use [Grant](https://grant-oauth.herokuapp.com/#/trello) for implementing the `authorization_code` flow - which is the one returning the token in the querystring instead of the hash.

Comment: @simo thanks . I want to use the authorise route to finish trello oauth. For the reason why **token** is returned after "#", I don't know whether it is due to my program issue or a bug of trello. If the others don't have this kinda issue, i should check the source or use the second method to implement trello oauth.

Comment: Check out this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33667003/parse-url-hash-fragment-in-express-application there is a very good explanation in the last comment. Also Trello uses OAuth1.0 which I'm not aware to have support for hash responses, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Got it. thanks for your information. :)